# How to run transaction in cloud_firestore_odm?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to run a transaction to update data in the Cloud Firestore using [`cloud_firestore_odm`](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore_odm).

This code works fine:

```dart
usersRef 
  .doc('foo_id')
  .update(
    name: 'John',
  );
```

But this one doesn't. I'm doing something wrong, can anyone tell me how to properly do it?

```dart
final transaction = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((_) async => _);

usersRef 
  .doc('foo_id')
  .transactionUpdate(
    transaction,
    name: 'John',
  );
```

Comment: Unrelated but you shouldn't return the parameter. Usage of the `Transaction` object should be contained within the runTransaction callback.

Comment: @RémiRousselet Yes, I never do, but just for putting a sample code to give users some hint I used that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Due to how the ODM works, the syntax for using transactions using the Firestore ODM is slightly different.

Instead of:

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  transaction.update(usersRef.doc('id'), {'age': 42});  
});
```

You should do:

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  usersRef.doc('id').transactionUpdate(transaction, age: 42);  
});
```

Basically, the `transaction` vs "reference" are swapped. But as a benefit, the transaction object is fully typed.

The same logic applies for any other transaction method.

Comment: Thanks, but please answer without me losing 50 in bounty next time, haha :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance((transaction) async {
   await transaction.update(usersRef.doc('foo_id'),{
     'name' : 'John'
   });
});
```

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't answer the question as I want to use `transactionUpdate` method which needs a `Transaction` and this is where I'm making the mistake. Your answer isn't taking advantage of odm. You're manually writing `name` field.